# Can not use Alt + F4 to close program when WPF application have a Webview

Tags: webview, windows-community-toolkit

My application have a Webview. It's fullscreen application. The problem is when I press Alt+F4, the application is not exit, nothing happen.

I think the Webview swallow the focus because: When I press Window key > Show start menu > press Window key again > Hide start menu > Alt + F4 > The application exit as expected.

I found that WPF WebBrowser have WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled but i can't find something like that in Windows community toolkit WebView.

Please help me to make Alt + F4 works. Thank you!

Comment: To someone vote -1: If you think the question is bad, please let me know by adding some reason.

Comment: I would think you'd have to handle this in the WebView code to catch the keyboard events and then pass up to the application.  I know I had to do this with the UWP WebView.

It works in the other scenario you describe as when you close the start menu, the focus is given back to the application window not the WebView, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it pragmatically by handling the WebView's AcceleratorKeyPressed event (checking for Alt+F4 and closing the window in this case).

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Controls:WebView ... AcceleratorKeyPressed="WebView_AcceleratorKeyPressed"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void WebView_AcceleratorKeyPressed(object sender, Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT.WebViewControlAcceleratorKeyPressedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.VirtualKey == Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT.VirtualKey.F4 && Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Alt))
        Close();
}
```